# WebSocket and Leap Motion

Tags: java, json, windows, websocket

I'm coding a little application in Java with Eclipse for use my Leap Motion device like a mouse. All is working when a run from Eclipse, is fast, is responsive and not freeze, crash or others.

I export the Java application to a Runnable `JAR`, I run it with `javaw -jar LeapMotionController.jar`

All is slow, reading and writing in the XML for configurations, establishing a connection to local web socket service.

The application has 3 Classes,

1. LeapMotion
2. SysTray
3. and Settings

The LeapMotion class is the main application, from this I start the Systray class and after I start the run command for initializing the connection.

```
SysTray.chgIcon("warn");
container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024);
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(1024);
session=container.connectToServer(LeapMotion.class, URI.create("ws://localhost:6437/v7.json"));
session.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(1024);
session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(1024);
wait4TerminateSignal();
```

> The wait4TerminateSignal is,

```
private static void  wait4TerminateSignal() {
    synchronized(waitLock) {
        try {
            for (;;) {
                waitLock.wait();
                if(session==null) {
                    waitLock.notify();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The Systray is showed after 1 second, after the read of the XML file for setup variables. The doc is loaded in variable for reuse (limit the read of the direct file).
After 5-10 secondes, I receive the first answer of the websocket, the handshake with info about the device version....

After, all message are queued and make a big buffer, I have tried two value (10 and 1024), one time is helped, after is gone very very slow.

In the task manager, I use 120MB of memory (of 32GB), cpu never go over 1.5% (I have 8 cores, 16 threads at 3.2GHz). The javaw process have 50-60 threads used.

I have also added a limit for drop activity. Is use a increment and when reach the value, work the message, and the increment is reset to 0.

You need to know about the Leap Motion Web Socket;
 - Make average of 110 messages per second, I can't control the amount
 - Not need to send a message to get a reply
 - Only output in JSon format

I have tested and searched about;
 - How optimise the Java (not find a real help)
 - Another way for use WebSocket, other need a message for get reply (chat)
 - use Elevator.exe (google it) for make the java in Admin right, not make change
 - Manually increase the process priority (little above, and Real Time), it's make no change
 - Not have found information about the buffer, and the code is one found on https://dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client (second part of code)

If I have miss information or want more details, leave me a comment.

I'm looking to increase the performance. With the amount of message and data I receive with the device, I can support queue drop or similar solution.

Thank in advance for your help.

(sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Please note; my internal drop is set to 0, no drop, I have also tested with higher value, no change for the exported jar
Each message receveid is evaluated, but make big time and others message is queued.

Comment: Changed
`wait4TerminateSignal();`
to
`boolean joy=false;
while(!joy) {}
` and not work more

Comment: I have continue my investigation, the problem is not only with the websocket. I have tried without them, (only systray and settings executed, but all compiled) and the read/save of XML file are slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have finally find the problem, this is the Java Runtime.

Since Java 1.8, is include more security. This cause many problem with; file read/write and tcp connections. Many users report a slow between 4 to 10 times more than 1.7.

I have installed and runned my application with Java 1.7, work very fast and not have any bugs.

For my project, I pack Java 1.7 with .jar to release it with right Java version.

Newer is not necessary better :P